# SCORM 2004 sequencing

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Anyone know where I can find some good examples, some good samples of SCORM 2004 sequencing? 
I cannot find any samples anywhere on the Internet , actual packages that illustrate SCORM sequencing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [these examples](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/) from scorm.com. They walk you through the creation of a SCORM package starting with the most basic content packaging and working all the way up to advanced sequencing.

Comment: Hello Mike , thanks for your reply,  I saw the examples, and when i tried to play these examples(Sequencing Examples, RTEs) in moodle and docebo demo sits, its showing errors :(

Comment: Hi Raki, That is probably because those platforms do not fully support SCORM 2004.